# GWT FileUpload Cell Type

Tags: gwt, file-upload, custom-cell, celltable

Hey guys i am making a celltable of contacts and would like to add the functionality to upload a picture with each contact. How can I add a FileUpload button to the cell table?

Answer (score 0):

You need a column that's `ButtonCell` then set a FieldUpdater tat pops up your upload dialog

```
    final ButtonCell buttonCell = new ButtonCell();


    Column column = new Column<Row,String>(buttonCell)
    {
        @Override
        public String getValue(Row object)
        {
        return (String) object.getCellValue(code);
        }
    };      

    column.setFieldUpdater(new FieldUpdater<Row, String>()
    {
        public void update(int index, Row row, String value)
        {
                         //show upload dialog
        }
    }
```